# Time-adjustable pulsed power debug tool

Tags: power-supply, integrated-circuit, pulse, thermal

For debugging DC thermal failures, I'd like to be able to limit power duration to be roughly in the range of 1ms to 5000ms, adjustably.  Here is one obvious way to do this:

[image: schematic]

You can assume that I have a bounce-free fast-ramping (less than 10us) battery applied from
VIN to GND.  The NMOS is sized to handle my voltage (12V) and current (2A) needs, but the same
tool could then be used more generally over a range of voltages and currents.  The pulsed power
output is from VIN to GND_SW.

So, what would a professional do here for a "time-adjustable pulsed power" or a "delay-adjustable shutdown" debug tool?

Is there a single-chip solution which only requires an external pot (i.e., the capacitor above is not required and the power NMOS is integrated with the control chip)?

Comment: Sounds like a potential 555 timer application.  There are literally books written on just 555 applications, (just one example: http://vtda.org/books/Electronics/ICTimerCookbook1stEd1977_WalterGJung.pdf)

Comment: @Nedd A 555 timer or CD4060 counter answer would be fine, but it would still need an external power transistor and some external Rs and Cs, so I don't think it will work out to be so nice...I was really hoping for some other new chip.